# Evdev and Hidraw devices

Tags: gpu, udev, passthru

I am currently using Evdev with GPU Passthru to switch my Keyboard and Mouse between host and guest. It works very well. Recently I rebuilt my mail rig using a Logitech Wireless Keyboard and Mouse. The Keyboard and mouse both work under Linux (Surprisingly!) but present themselves as HIDRAW devices. I am using SOLAAR to manage the WIrelss Logitech dongles and that is also working great. So I have 2 questions.

1. Does Evdev work with Hhidraw devices?
2. If Evdev DOES work with Hidraw devices is there somthing special that needs to be done to get this working? No matter what I do, I either get, 'Device does not exist' or "Permission Denied' which at least gives me a little Hope. I have tried various Udev rules permissions etc. I would REALLY LIKE to get this Logitech keyboard and mouse working, otherwise I haveta go back to my Wired devices!

Current Hardwares

AMD 7800 CPU - MSI-x670e Carbon - 64 Gig Kingston Fury DDR5 6000 mhz - 3x4tb Kingston Predator NVME - ASUS 3081ti / EVGA 2080ti - 1000 watt PSU. Current OS is LMDE (Kernel 6.1)

As stated I have tried UDEV rules, changed permissions nothing has worked. IF it does work I should be able to hit Ctrl / Ctrl and the HidRaw keyboard and Mouse should swap between between host and guest.

Just a bit more info if anyone is interested. So this is how I am using Evdev in my VM script.

```
<qemu:arg value='input-linux,id=mouse1,evdev=/dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_USB_Gaming_Mouse-event-mouse'/>

<qemu:arg value='input-linux,id=kbd1,evdev=/dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_K840_Mechanical_Corded_Keyboard_038638573436-event-kbd,grab_all=on,repeat=on'/>
```

As mentioned above this works great for me. I would like to be able to do the same with HIDRAW devices but so far have been unable to do so. I would like to basically change this:

qemu:arg value='input-linux,id=mouse1,evdev=/dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_USB_Gaming_Mouse-event-mouse'/>

to

qemu:arg value='input-linux,id=mouse1,evdev=/dev/hidraw2'

thus my question does EvDev work with/support HIDRAW devices? I have had no luck getting this to work so far, I am wondering if it is even possible .....

Any response is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Oh well I guess it's not possible ....